# About Wikipedia Miner

Tags: java

I have a requirement where if I query for a word the system should tell weather the word represents a persons first name or last name or some disease or a country etc. I have heard about Wikipedia miner but I don't know which one to use. Can anyone guide me on this topic. If this is not possible with the Wikipedia miner, is there any other API to fetch this type of information?

Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: A word can be multiple of these. I would use google to do the searching ;) e.g. Georgia is a first name, last name, state of the USA, country and they have diseases there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can find no version of wikipedia-miner toolkit newer than 1.2 available [on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikipedia-miner/)

There are several articles online about wikipedia-miner and its use in word sense disambiguation such as http://fedcsis.org/proceedings/fedcsis2012/pliks/253.pdf